# What can I possibly be?

Tags: riddle

> I'm open and not closed
>
> or closed but not open.
>
> If I'm not, though I can be,
>
> open and closed
>
> or neither closed nor open.

---

> Hint: math

Comment: I'm voting to close... or open... ARGH, I'M SO CONFUSED! ;-)

Comment: Hopefully the answer is not related to body part of seniors..

Comment: @Alex rot13(vg vf abg) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sets? Because they can be open, closed, both or neither open or closed?

Answer (score 2):

Are you a(n)

> interval?

I'm open and not closed

> If an interval does not contain its endpoints it is open.

or closed but not open.

> A closed interval does contain its endpoints.

If I'm not, though I can be,

open and closed

> A half-open interval contains only one of its endpoints.

or neither closed nor open.

> A degenerate interval only consists of one real number.

Hint:

> An interval in math is a set of (real) numbers lying between the extremities.

Comment: hmm, this wasn't my original intention. The 'thing' could be both open and closed or neither closed nor open. I've edited the puzzle to reflect this clarification

Comment: @jazhang Next guess?